# Logo in BootStrap navbar-brand class behaving weridly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive HTML page using bootstrap css. I am using the `navbar-brand` class in which there is a logo. The code for that segment is:

```
<div class="grad">
       <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-logo" href="http://someUrl"><img src="images/someLogo.gif" height="43" alt="logo"></a>
       <div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav mycss-aligned">
              <li><span class="name">LastName, FirstName</span></li>
              <li><span class="logo1">some</span><span class="logo2">Stuff</span></li>
              </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

That `mycss-aligned` is just a few dimensions for the list below it and is not relevant to our problem so I am not sharing it. The relevant CSS from BootStrap has been slightly modified by me to suit my needs and it is as follows:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left:125%;
    margin-top:-5%;
}
```

I have a HTML `div` which is `center aligned` and has `60% width` of total screen. I am trying to match the start of the division with the start of the logo. While I can achieve this, as you can see, I am required to use an unusually high percentage for the `margin-left` value in  `.navbar-brand>img`. That being said, Even when I can achieve that, the design is barely responsive and the logo does not slide across along with the division when the page is resized. The funny thing is

```
   <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav mycss-aligned">
          <li><span class="name">LastName, FirstName</span></li>
          <li><span class="logo1">some</span><span class="logo2">Stuff</span></li>
          </ul>
   </div
```

is perfectly responsive. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you provided a live example in codepen or jsfiddle. Also what styles do the grad class apply on the parent div?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fodhxg0a/

There you go.. I want that logo to move so that it is always aligned with the first letter of the text division

Comment: Why bother using a default bootstrap class like navbar-brand if you're not going to use it within the structure it was intended [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) You'd be betting off just using your own class.

Comment: So you want the logo to line up with the paragraph below? Right?

Comment: @Hoshts yes that is what I want

Comment: What about the 'Last name, first name' part? Should that be aligned to right side of the screen or to the right side of the paragraph content?

Comment: @Hoshts yes, that too.

Comment: As in align to screen or to paragraph? Read last comment again :)

Comment: Apologies my friend. To the right side of Paragraph content. As in the The last letters of content in that div should match the last letters in right aligned navbar content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest that you use more of the bootstrap components to create a context for the elements you want to use. E.g. there is a `navbar-fixed-top` class.

You can [see my fork of the code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/em5Lsk7a/2/) There is an outline on all divs to visualise the alignment.

Here is how I would write the same

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-content">
               <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-logo" href="http://someUrl">
                    <img  src="images/someLogo.gif" height="43" alt="logo">
                </a>

                <ul class="navbar-list">
                    <li><span class="name">LastName, FirstName</span>

                    </li>
                    <li><span class="logo1">Some</span><span class="logo2">Stuff</span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="width: 60%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:justify;">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>This is just some uberRandom text to show how the division is getting aligned and justified
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

And the re-written css

```
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(white, grey);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
}

.navbar-content {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.navbar-list {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Notice how there is an inner content of the navbar that is set to same width as the actual content (the paragraph). That way you don't have to use those silly margins and the image and text should align.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Worked perfectly. I think the issue was with the way navbar component is used. While it is quite flexible, it does not accept some changes easily.